# Beginner questions - Variables inside and outside of functions

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to Javascript and have a beginner question in regards to declaring and accessing variables. Why does the console.log show me that the textContent of "text" has been changed when it hasn't? I can get the function to work if I instead of declaring "text" OUTSIDE of the function declare it inside - then the actual textContent change

```js
let text = document.querySelector("#text").textContent

function changeText() {
  text = "Goodbye"
}

changeText()
console.log(text)
```

```html
<p id="text">Hi</p>
```

Comment: Are you asking why `text` is not a reference to `document.querySelector("#text").textContent`?

Comment: _"I can get the function to work if I instead of declaring 'text' OUTSIDE of the function declare it inside - then the actual textContent change"_ That's not true: https://jsfiddle.net/7h2ej3L1/

Comment: @jabaa I guess I am yeah! If I declare "let textElement = document.querySelector("#text").textContent" inside of the function, it lets me change the textContent but not when I declare it outside. 

Btw: changed the variable name to textElement for clarification

Comment: _"If I declare '`let textElement = document.querySelector("#text").textContent`' inside of the function, it lets me change the textContent but not when I declare it outside."_ That's not true. I posted a link in my comment that proves you're wrong.

Comment: @Dohjo I changed it back to `text` as otherwise that would a) invalidate existing answers b) introduce an inconsistency as you still did `console.log(text)`

Comment: @Bergi And probably it's important that the variable name and the element ID are the same for this question. Because if `text` is declared inside the function and accessed outside the function, it will access the actual HTML element with this ID (in most current browsers).

Comment: @jabaa I didn't want to open [that can of worms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1048572) because `let text` should actually shadow the `window.text` element just fine, I don't thin there's a problem here. (I had assumed that when OP said "move the declaration inside the function", they'd move the `console.log` as well)

Comment: @Bergi I think that's the actual problem here but OP didn't provide a reproducible code. I guess OP is accessing the HTML element through its ID by accident. As you can see in the JSFiddle in my comment, the `console.log` prints the HTML element, because I moved the declaration into the function. _"I can get the function to work if I instead of declaring "text" OUTSIDE of the function declare it inside - then the actual textContent change"_ doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assignment:

```
let text = document.querySelector("#text").textContent
```

stores a **copy** of the value of `document.querySelector("#text").textContent` in `text`. The is no explicit or implicit connection between `text` and `document.querySelector("#text").textContent`. You know have **two** places that happen to contain the same value.

You then proceed update one of the places to contain a different value:

```
text = "Goodbye"
```

This has no effect on the other place whatsoever.

This is also isn't specific to the DOM. That's the case with variables and/or properties in general. Here are some more examples:

```js
var a = 1;
var b = a;
a = 2;
console.log('a:', a, 'b:', b);
b = 3;
console.log('a:', a, 'b:', b);
```

```js
var a = {content: 1};
var b = a.content;
a.content = 2;
console.log('a:', a, 'b:', b);
b = 3;
console.log('a:', a, 'b:', b);
```

The technical term for this is [*pass-by-value*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value): If you assign/pass a memory location *A* (variable, property, etc) to memory location *B*, then *B* is assigned a copy of the value of *A*, not a reference or pointer to *A*.

See also [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/218196)

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize your `text` variable at the top you’re setting its value to “Hi” (because that’s the textContent of your element) but it’s a copy of the value, completely independent of the DOM element. Changing one has no effect on the other.

So when you then update it (via `text = “Goodbye”`) you’re just changing the value of the variable, not the DOM element.